# cbind recycled rows to add to last row in R

Tags: r, cbind

I have a question about cbinding recycled items. I simplified my problem  into the following code.

I have two objects "a" and "b". "a" has 5 rows and "b" has 10 rows.

When I cbind them, I get a data.frame with 10 rows, and my column "a" recycles until it reaches 10 rows. My problem is, how do i recycle the values so it adds to the length(a). Thanks!

```
a <- c(4, 3, 5, 2, 8)
b <- c(1:10)

cbind(a,b)


   a  b
1  4  1
2  3  2
3  5  3
4  2  4
5  8  5
6  4  6
7  3  7
8  5  8
9  2  9
10 8 10

What I want to do: a[6] = a[5] + 4, a[7] = a[5] + 5, ... a[10] = a[5] + 8


   a  b
1  4  1
2  3  2
3  5  3
4  2  4
5  8  5
6  12  6
7  11  7
8  13  8
9  10  9
10 16 10
```

Comment: Suppose your `a <- c(4, 3, 5, 2, 8)`, what will be the `after` dataset after `cbind`?

Comment: Please try to add more information, your question is not clear at all. How should your program determine the values that are not in a?

Comment: Please provide more examples or a clearer explanation.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I changed "a" to akrun's response

Comment: maybe c(4,3,5,2,8,14,13,15,12,18) or c(4,3,5,2,8,9,8,10,7,13)instead of what you have added? It's still unlear to me, I'm sorry mate.

Comment: @NoVice The expected output is not clear as naltipar suggested

Comment: @NoVice Your expected output may be `cbind(a=c(a,a+a[length(a)])[1:length(b)],b)`, but I didn't understand it correctly.  For example, suppose `b <- 1:15`

Comment: I believe the OP  meant c(4,3,5,2,8,9,8,10,7,13), otherwise the OP's question makes no sense.

Comment: Judging from the question, I don't think you understand what "recycling" means.  R does this internally.  You can't control the values that are added via recycling unless you change the vector that is being recycled, and possibly changing  the length of the vectors it being compared to

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? I have 5 items and I'm adding a[5] to the the next 5 items, 2*a[5] to the next 5 items and so on.

```
a <- c(4, 3, 5, 2, 8)
b <- c(1:11)
counter <-0:floor(length(b)-1)/length(a))
new.col <- rep(a[length(a)] * counter, each = length(a)) + a
length(new.col) <- length(b)
new.col
[1]  4  3  5  2  8 12 11 13 10 16
```

The first length(a) items stay intact, we add a[5] to the next length(a) items, 2*a[5] to the next length(a) items and so on...